# how to copy a folder contained in my project to anothe location when i am installing project

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

We created windows application using c# .In that we created lot of Reports using `Microsoft Report Viewer` and `Rdlc Pages` .But when we are installing the project in another system,report will not generate  because it shows an error like

> Could not find the file Report.rdlc

So how to solve it?Is it is possible to copy the folder which contains Rdlc pages in my system into specified location of target system when i am installing the application?

or

Any other way to give permanent path or relative path?
I created reports using Microsoft Report Viewer and Rdlc .my code is

```
            reportViewer1.Reset();

            con.Open();
            Manufactures ds = new Manufactures();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Stp_ManufacturerReport_Fetch", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName", cbCompName.Text);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //da.Fill(ds, "Manufactures");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "D:\\Abhith\\TTS\\Cabin\\TTS form Beta\\TTS form Beta\\Manufacturer.rdlc";//PATH OF REPORT
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Manufactures_ManufacturerReport", dt));//FILLING SOURCE FOR REPORT
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();//REFRESHING THE REPORT`.
```

The problem is with the path.When i am using this application in another system,can't find the path.So report is not generating.Any solution?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail on the specific problem? Without any more info on your folder layout or your code it is impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I created reports using Microsoft Report Viewer and Rdlc .my code is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have specified the `Build action` on my `.rdlc` file as `Embedded Resource` and then it is referenced like this in the code:

```
this.reportViewerScraps.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Backa_Artiklar_2.ScrapReportDocument.rdlc";
```

**EDIT:** Added info according to askers comment

I have the `rdlc` file here in the Solution Explorer:

[image: rdlc in Solution Explorer]

Change your line of code to:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "<namespace>.Manufacturer.rdlc";
```

Remember to change `<namespace>` to your application namespace